# How to get proper integer value of distance from Polyline in Google Map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, parsing

Ok, I'm getting distance from polyline like this:

```
distance = polylineData.getLeg().distance.toString();
```

I get String like "44.5 km" or "123 km". After that I parse it to Double like this:

```
distance = distance.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
distance = distance.replaceAll(" ", ".");
distance = distance.substring(0, distance.length() - 1);
double dist = new Double(Double.parseDouble(distance));
```

I get Double like "44.5" or "123.0" and everything is fine. But,
if distance is 1000 km and above I get String like "1.378 km" and after parsing I get "1.378", but I need "1378" and I cannot find the solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`inMeters` field](http://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.1.6/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/Distance.html) instead of calling toString():

```
double distanceInMeters = polylineData.getLeg().distance.inMeters;
```

If you need the distance in km, divide by 1000.0